# How To Locate a File From Mapped Network Drive in PHP?

Tags: php

The file I need to locate is in 192.168.100.4 > Drive D:

File locating works well on local drives tho.

```
$path = "\\\\192.168.100.4\\d\\file.mdb";
if (!file_exists($path))
{
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLKl3.png)

[This is my drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3kT5.png)